# Is it possible to string interpolate the input for a cron trigger in a pipeline Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to do the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    parameters {
        string(name: 'PARAM_1', defaultValue: '0 5 * * *', description: 'cron value for PARAM_1')
        string(name: 'PARAM_2', defaultValue: '0 9 * * 4', description: 'cron value for PARAM_2')
    }
    triggers {
        cron("${params.PARAM_1} \n ${params.PARAM_2}")
    }
    ...
    // Do additional logic with parameters in stage
}
```

When I do the above, I get the following error:

```
line 1:1: unexpected char: 'n'
    at hudson.scheduler.CrontabLexer.nextToken(CrontabLexer.java:184)
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69)
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80)
    at antlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52)
    at hudson.scheduler.CrontabParser.startRule(CrontabParser.java:53)
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTab.set(CronTab.java:118)
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTab.<init>(CronTab.java:100)
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTabList.create(CronTabList.java:121)
Caused: antlr.ANTLRException: Invalid input: "null"
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTabList.create(CronTabList.java:123)
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTabList.create(CronTabList.java:96)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger.<init>(Trigger.java:170)
    at hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.<init>(TimerTrigger.java:58)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor510.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:272)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1336.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callSafe(AbstractCallSite.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils.instantiateDescribable(Utils.groovy:455)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils$instantiateDescribable$18.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:189)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onStaticCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:187)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:191)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:98)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {spec=null 
 null} for hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:272)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1336.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callSafe(AbstractCallSite.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils.instantiateDescribable(Utils.groovy:455)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils$instantiateDescribable$18.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:189)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onStaticCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:187)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:191)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:98)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(ModelInterpreter.groovy:61)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:84)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:107)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:87)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I thought you can do string interpolation with double quotes in the Jenkinsfile/Groovy. Are the parameters just not defined until after the triggers hit? Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this in a different manner:

```
def PARAM_1 = '0 5 * * *'
def PARAM_2 = '0 9 * * 4'
pipeline {
    agent none
    triggers {
        cron("${PARAM_1} \n ${PARAM_2}")
    }
    ...
    // Do additional logic with parameters in stage
}
```